# kendo script reference other than kendo.all.min.js

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Using Kendo in a new project, loving the grid, charts and date pickers!  However, in their documentation and examples, they always reference kendo.all.min.js.  Anyone know where to find the relevant scripts and css files pertaining to specific widgets only?  Currently the all.js file is taking 400 - 550 ms in the network tab.  Adding that to my other resources, my page loads are 3-5 seconds which is not ideal. Thanks much!

Comment: check this https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/tree/master/src

Comment: Thanks. I have the library, I just wish they didn't reference Kendo.all.js in their demo's.  It would be nice to know the exact scripts required for each widget so that I can lower my footprint.

Answer (score 1):

There's a custom download builder tool. You can find the link on this [page](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/what-you-need). But, you have to have the license, of course.